# Missing 42.0.0 arhetype on maven for Tridion Integration Framework

Tags: java, 9.6, tif

When I try to execute mvn generate for new Java tridion Integration framework template, for sites 9.6 (version 42.0.0) i get the exception.

Does anyone has any idea where to get it from?
[image]

Comment: Did you try using it from here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sdl.tridion.connectorframework/tcf-archetype/42.0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following:

1. Go to https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sdl/tridion/connectorframework/tcf-archetype/42.0.0/
2. Download tcf-archetype-42.0.0.maven-archetype file and rename it to tcf-archetype-42.0.0.jar
3. Copy renamed file to C:\Users\{UserName}\.m2\repository\com\sdl\tridion\connectorframework\tcf-archetype\42.0.0
4. Execute mvn archetype:generate command

Answer (score 2):

You see that there's a 42.0.0 version and a 42.0.0-1 version of the archetype. The former one was problematic (as you've noticed) and a fixed 42.0.0-1 version has been published.

You should use the 42.0.0-1 version. See: https://docs.rws.com/1099777/830905/tridion-sites-10-connectors/creating-a-connector-using-the-template-for-java

BTW: TIF 42.0.0 is compatible with Tridion Sites 9.6 and higher. If you want to create a Connector which can be used with an older version of Tridion Sites, you should use an older version of the archetype.